# How to access two elements of a splitted String at a time?

Tags: java

**Problem:** I have a String `100, 200, boxes`. I want to convert this String into an object, let's say `TreeMap<String, List>`, with `100, 200` as a List of values and `boxes` as a String that is a key.
The result should look like `[100, 200]: "boxes"`.

Later I would like to access the values: `my_map.get("boxes")[0]` or `my_map.get("boxes")[1]` for example.

**My Solution:** Let's say I have a file with 3 columns, I read the data, split it and iterate over each line splitting the line on the go. I assume I have `[100, 200, "boxes"]`. Now in python I could simply access the elements I need by providing a range of indexes like `[0:1]`.

How to do the same thing in Java?

```
for (String line : mydata.split("\n|\r\n")) {

            String[] sl = line.split(" |\t");
            String[] my_two_elements = sl[0:1]; <-- No way!

        }
```

Comment: It should be `TreeMap<String, List>`. The first parameter type in the map is the key.

Comment: I would advise you to rephrase the question title, as it is confusing.

Comment: Do you want a String or a String[]-array as result?

Comment: Create a new array and store the elements in it: `String[] array = new String[] { sl[0], sl[1] };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Arrays.copyOfRange(array,from,to);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int))

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.
>   The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and
>   original.length, inclusive. The value at original[from] is placed into
>   the initial element of the copy (unless from == original.length or
>   from == to). Values from subsequent elements in the original array are
>   placed into subsequent elements in the copy. The final index of the
>   range (to), which must be greater than or equal to from, may be
>   greater than original.length, in which case null is placed in all
>   elements of the copy whose index is greater than or equal to
>   original.length - from. The length of the returned array will be to -
>   from.
>
> The resulting array is of exactly the same class as the original
>   array.

Always refer to the source for implementation details and profile your code for performance.

```
3035    public static <T,U> T[] More ...copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
3036        int newLength = to - from;
3037        if (newLength < 0)
3038            throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
3039        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
3040            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
3041            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
3042        System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
3043                         Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
3044        return copy;
3045    }
```

Comment: Is it efficient enough to create a new array on every loop? Imagine I have 10k iterations?